# emulated prompt cant change directory

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and wanted to write a small prompt, but I've now found that if I use the cd command in this prompt, the direcotry doesn't change

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int run();
void runCMD(std::string cmd);

int main() {
    run();
    return 0;
}
int run(){
    std::cout << "->";
    std::string line;
    std::getline( std::cin, line );
   // std::cout << line << std::endl;
    runCMD(line);
    main();
}
void runCMD(std::string cmd){
    char* cm = const_cast<char *>(cmd.c_str());
    system(cm);
}
```

the output is an arrow where i can enter commands

```
->echo hi
hi
->ls 
...
```

but i can't use cd the command is accepted but not executed

```
->mkdir test
->ls
CMakeCache.txt      build.ninja     test
CMakeFiles      cli
Testing         cmake_install.cmake
->cd test
->ls
CMakeCache.txt      build.ninja     test
CMakeFiles      cli
Testing         cmake_install.cmake
```

same dir

I kind of don't get it.

Many thanks if you can help me

Comment: It is executed, but in a different shell, which is closed after the command finished. The next command is again executed in a different shell.

Comment: ohhh ok and is there a way to display the other shell or run it in the same shell? Something like this?

Comment: No, there isn't. You need to manage the working directory yourself. See `man 2 chdir`.

Comment: Congratulations. You have just learned that some commands are built-in commands of the command line interpreter and not every command is an executable. Your implementation needs to be similar: the CD command needs to be handled by yourself and call [`current_path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path) instead of `system`. You'll have similar problems with variables